# Next.js 11 TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, babeljs, babel-loader

After updating Next.js from 10 to 11, I get the following error when running `npm run build`:

```
Module parse failed: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
File was processed with these loaders: * ./node_modules/next/dist/build/babel/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined>

Build error occurredError: > Build failed because of webpack errors
```

It seems like an issue triggered by using the spread operator, since the build is successful if I remove all uses of spread operators.

I found these similar issues but none of them are specific to Next.js 11:

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7753
- https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12335

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here in order to hopefully save someone a couple hours of debugging:

I was able to fix this issue by updating Next.js from `11.0.1` to `11.1.0`.

However, even though this fixed the problem I still don't know what the root cause was and haven't found any related fixes in the [changelog](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases), so answers are appreciated.